# How can i set the state from a value coming from a picker rigth after the component render in REACT NATIVE with EXPO?

Tags: react-native

After an axios.get i have an array of object to map all the Picker.Item, the issue is if exist only one picker item, the state never update. Even with few picker items, if i select the first option the state never change. i have to select another one and then the state change.

Expo sdk 38,
@react-native-community/picker

```
    const [zoneId, setZoneId] = useState("")
useEffect(() => {
    requestZone();
  }, []);
return (    
zones && (
            <Picker
              mode="dropdown"
              selectedValue={zoneId}
              onValueChange={(value) => {
                setZoneId(value);
              }}
            >
              {zones.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <Picker.Item label={item.zone} value={item.id} key={index} />
                );
              })}
            </Picker>
          )
        )}
      </View>
      <View>
            <Text>zone id: {zoneId}</Text>
      </View>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of conditionally rendering the picker when `zones` has a value, why not render it when `zoneId` has a value?

```js
{zoneId ? <Picker /> : <ActivityIndicator />}
```

This way, when the Picker is rendered, `zoneId` will already be set as default.

Comment: Because zoneId value come from the picker, zones is just the array with all zones objects.